# Convert Pandas groupby group into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to group a Pandas dataframe by two separate group types, A_Bucket and B_Bucket, and convert each A_Bucket group into a column. I get the groups as such:

```
grouped = my_new_df.groupby(['A_Bucket','B_Bucket'])
```

I want the A_Bucket group to be in columns and the B_Bucket group to be the indices.  'A' has about 20 values and B has about 20 values, so there are a total of about 400 groups.

When I print grouped and its type I get:

```
type of grouped2 = <class 'pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy'>
A_Bucket  B_Bucket
0.100      100.0            5.418450
           120.0           18.061367
0.125      80.0             3.100920
           100.0           14.137063
           120.0           30.744823
           140.0           38.669950
           160.0           48.303129
           180.0           74.576333
           200.0          125.119950
0.150      60.0             0.003200
           80.0             2.274807
           100.0            5.350074
           120.0           23.272970
           140.0           40.131780
           160.0           47.036912
           180.0           72.438978
           200.0          117.365480
```

So A_Bucket group 0.100 has only 2 values, but 0.125 has 7.  I want a dataframe like this:

```
        0.1     0.125      0.15
80      NaN     3.10092    2.274807
100     5.41845 14.137063  5.350074
120     18.0613 30.744823  23.27297
140     NaN     38.66995   40.13178
160     NaN     48.303129  47.036912
180     NaN     74.576333  72.438978
200     NaN     125.11995  NaN
```

I saw this question:
[Pandas groupby result into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024023/pandas-groupby-result-into-multiple-columns)

but I don't understand the syntax, and it doesn't arrange the first group into columns like I need. I also want this to work for more than one output column.

How do I do this?

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the trick.  It repeats indices many times and has many more columns.  I expect to have a dataframe about 20x20, but this gives 186 x 318.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't read your question very carefully. So you actually want to reshape your data frame from long to wide format. One question though, it seems you didn't do any aggregation after the groupby?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't put it there.  I want to take the mean of each group/subgroup.  For one output column I expect a 20 x 20, but for 2 output columns I'm not sure what the dataframe would look like.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to reshape your data frame instead of grouping by summary, in this case you can use `set_index()` and `unstack()`:

```
df.set_index(["A_Bucket", "B_Bucket"]).unstack(level=0)

#              Value
# A_Bucket     0.100     0.125       0.150
# B_Bucket          
#     60.0       NaN       NaN    0.003200
#     80.0       NaN  3.100920    2.274807
#    100.0  5.418450 14.137063    5.350074
#    120.0 18.061367 30.744823   23.272970
#    140.0       NaN 38.669950   40.131780
#    160.0       NaN 48.303129   47.036912
#    180.0       NaN 74.576333   72.438978
#    200.0       NaN 125.119950 117.365480
```

If you indeed have done the summary after grouping by, you can still do `df.groupby(['A_Bucket', 'B_Bucket']).mean().unstack(level=0)`

Comment: Yes, the second one (with the mean()) is what worked perfectly. I understand the unstack better now.  Thank you!