# How to group by certain columns and invert the group by in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So I have a Data Frame for which there is the same ID contains multiple Custom Fields. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024023/pandas-groupby-result-into-multiple-columns) but it's not quite what I am looking for.  Code to create desired starter data frame below

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ID'] = [np.random.randint(1,2000) for x in range(0,1000)]
new = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(0,10):
    new = new.append(df)
new = new.sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
new['Custom Field'] = [np.random.randint(1,20) for x in new['ID']]
new['Value'] = [np.random.randint(0,10000000) for x in new['ID']]
new = new.groupby(['ID','Custom Field']).first().reset_index()
new = new.sort_values(['ID','Custom Field']).reset_index(drop=True)
new.head()
```

[image]

Essentially the below picture is what I am looking for:
[image]

This image shows that it's taking the values in the Custom Field table and transposing them into separate columns. For every ID it can have up to 20 values in the Custom Field table. I need each of the custom field values (1-20) to be in their own column. If a certain ID does not have the value, it will be blank. I am trying to be as specific as possible but it's hard to explain. Let me know if I need to edit the question to provide more detail.

Comment: You should set a seed so your data and results can be reproduced.

Comment: Add the text version

Comment: How do I set a seed? Also I've created the data so that it always has the parameters I need.

Comment: This sounds like a `long to wide` question

Comment: try to look at pivot or pivot_table

Comment: Maybe `new.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Custom Field', values='Value')`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I think only pivot is enough

Comment: The Pivot Table worked! Closing Question

Comment: Next time search before asking and post only text than images. Hard to convert them to text.

Comment: I searched for hours but I was using the wrong nomenclature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pivot with add prefix i.e

```
df.pivot('ID','Custom_Field','Value').add_prefix('CF')
```

```
Custom_Field        CF1        CF2        CF3        CF7        CF8  \
ID                                                                    
1                   NaN  5643962.0  6959658.0  4310939.0  5796051.0   
2             1121049.0  6044077.0        NaN        NaN        NaN   

Custom_Field        CF9       CF12       CF13       CF15       CF16       CF19  
ID                                                                              
1             1198701.0        NaN  2925189.0  8438978.0  1730570.0  3481493.0  
2             4483108.0  3327149.0        NaN  2700632.0        NaN  3249005.0
```